# Linking an external file with svg code to main index

Tags: html, css, svg, frontend, web-deployment

Keeping multiline svg code in main index page is very inelegant. I'm looking for solution which let me move that code to another file and just link this file in my page, in place when it should be. Something like:

```
<svg><use href="linkedfile.svg"></use></svg>
```

but the sollution above doesn't work properly - an image is formatting very frank and cannot be modify by css. I need good-working method.

Comment: Why not use the normal `<img />` tag?

Comment: I need to use css to styling - commands like fill:color

Comment: There's pretty limited CSS modification of use too. And the restriction that use cannot point to an entire SVG file, it must point to some element within that file.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried a background image in your CSS file?

```
.image{
 background: url(linkedfile.svg);
}
```